# accessing array elements from pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im new to c++, and Ive read a lot of posts on stack overflow about this issue. Please tell me what Im not understanding, it seems basic....so why?

```
int* getArray() {
    int a[] = { 3, 4, 3, 1, 5 };    
    return a;
}

void main() {
    int *result = getArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

returns:

3

263996040

-1

4651964

263540469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice one. The array you created in your function stops existing when the function returns.

You can make it "persist" by adding the `static` keyword:

```
int* getArray() {
    static int a[] = { 3, 4, 3, 1, 5 };    
    return a;
}

void main() {
    int *result = getArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`static` makes the array remain in memory after the function returns - usually because you want to use it again in the function. It is considered "ugly" to do the above, but it works...

What you are seeing is the fact that the memory, once freed after the return from `getArray()`, is happily being re-used for other purposes. In fact there is no telling what ends up in there (possibly some temporary storage for the `cout` function), and when you interpret it as an `int` (because you are accessing these memory locations with the `int *a` pointer), you will just see the `int` representation of whatever bytes happen to be there.

**update** the "not quite so ugly way" to do this:

```
int getArray(int *a, int n) {
    int ii, lim;
    int temp[]= { 3, 4, 3, 1, 5 };          // temp exists in scope of function, will disappear after
    lim = (sizeof(temp),n)?sizeof(temp):n;  // copy no more than exist in temp, 
                                            // or than there is space in a
    for(ii = 0; ii < lim; ii++) {
      a[ii] = temp[ii];               // copy temp to "permanent" location
    }
    return lim;                         // this now returns the size of the array
}

void main() {
  int a[10];     // deliberately allocating too much space...
  int b;
  b = getArray(a);  // function returns actual number of elements allocated    
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: so if I wanted to generate an array inside a function and then return it. How might I do it in the un-ugly way?

Comment: Or maybe I should move the array to a higher scope?

Comment: You would pass the location to the array. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a temporary variable which will be deconstructed after the function getArray finishes execution. So "result" points to some memory that is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "local" variable (stack allocated memory) and return it back. Instead use dynamic (heap allocated memory) variable and return it back and ask the caller to destroy it after use.

Like this...

```
void getArray(int** a, int &size)
{
    size = 5;
    // Allocate memory on heap so it remain accessible until destroyed explicitly.
    int *arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    *a = arr;
    return;
}

int main() {
    int *a = NULL;
    int arrSize = 0;

    getArray(&a, arrSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Release/Destroy the memory. DON'T FORGET TO CALL THIS ONCE YOU ARE DONE with 'a' !!
    delete a;

}
```